# What is the proper way to generate the private link to an Evernote note?

Tags: authentication, evernote

I want to programatically generate the *private* note link to an Evernote note.  (In my scenario, it is just me as the developer authenticating using my auth token - there is no OAuth involved, but I am assuming the process would be the same.)

I've read article "Note Links - Link directly to individual notes from anywhere" at https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php but it covers evernote://... links only.

What is the proper way to generate a private Evernote note link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on what you want to do. https:// links will open in your browser, whereas evernote:// ones will open in the client application (if there's one installed).
2. Sharing a note privately means that you share a note to individuals. Only these individuals will be able to access the note after being authenticated. On the contrary, public sharing means that you share the note with everybody that knows the url.
   From what I understand about your case, I'd say that you don't have to "share" a note. You don't want to "invite" someone to access a note but just want that the owner of a note can access it via a link. Am I right ?

If so, you have to stick to the documentation at https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php 
The main difficulty being to handle the different cases mentioned in the doc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In retrospect my first question was kind of dumb, so I am going to edit my question to remove that.  Regarding your question to me in #2 - you are exactly right - I will reword my question for that also.  The https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note_links.php article talks about evernote://... urls only.  I grabbed a link to one of my own notes and saw the format was: https://*host*.evernote.com/shard/*shardID*/nl/*userid*/*noteguid* and that did work, however it feels fragile because link structures may change.  I'd rather find an Evernote article about how to construct the link.

Comment: FYI, just saw at https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_User that shardid has been deprecated.  However, shardid is still referenced in many many other articles.

Comment: Yep, I just noticed that too. But as it is used in the very brand new  version of the iOS SDK, i'd say that it's pretty safe to rely on it for now. I'll ask to Evernote about that inconstancy and let you informed.

Comment: Wonderful thank you  Could you also ask if they have a formal definition for how to construct the private http://... note links?

Comment: I finally found on the Evernote dev forums that the https://*host*.evernote.com/shard/*shardID*/nl/*userid*/*noteguid* format is indeed the spec.   If you edit your answer to reflect that I changed my question (per my comment above - thanks to the good points you made) and put this format as the answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share a note and only send the URL to the person in question.  Evernote URLs were designed to keep people from guessing them so if you only share the URL with one other person you can reasonably assume that they are the only one that has access to the note.  The URL scheme is below

```
[EN_URL]/shard/[shardId]/sh/[noteGuid]/[shareKey]
```

where

- [EN_URL] is your URL (https://sandbox.evernote.com for the sandbox or https://www.evernote.com for the production service
- [shardId] the Shard id that the note user is on (can be accessed via userStore.getUser().shardId)
- [noteGuid] is the note guid (can be access via note.guid)
- [shareKey] is the share key from sharing the note (returned from the note.shareNote() method)

You can see all of this in the Evernote API docs: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/note-sharing.php

see the sanbox python example below:

```
from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient
import evernote.edam.type.ttypes as Types

EN_URL="https://sandbox.evernote.com"
evernote_auth_token = "Your auth or dev token here"

client = EvernoteClient(token=evernote_auth_token, sandbox=True)
user_store = client.get_user_store()
note_store = client.get_note_store()    

note = Types.Note() #create a note object

#define a sample note           
note.title='some title'
note.content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
note.content += '<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM ' \
    '"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">'
note.content += '<en-note>'+'hi mom!'+'<br/>'
note.content += '</en-note>'

note=note_store.createNote(note) # create the note

user=user_store.getUser(evernote_auth_token)
shardId=user.shardId
shareKey=note_store.shareNote(evernote_auth_token, note.guid)
evernote_url="%s/shard/%s/sh/%s/%s" % (EN_URL,shardId,note.guid,shareKey)
```

Comment: I am looking to get a note's private URL, not to generate the URL for a shared note. Sharing does not apply in this case.